# Is there a good conditional code for my idea?

Tags: javascript, html, passwords, conditional-statements, blogger

I tried to set a code (HTML or Javascript) which can help me in y Blog.
My idea is:

Depending on the tag (Category of this post)
then show something in my case is requesting a password for that category.
I have the pass request already, I'm missing the conditional, I've tried

This is the password request code:

```
</style>

<script languaje="javascript">
var getin = prompt("Whats the password?")
if (getin!="AbCD")
{location.href='https://dekanimex.blogspot.com/p/pass.html'}
else
{alert('Good')}

</script>
```

Now I found these codes and combined with the previous one, placing the tag link and nothing happens.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "link of the category"'>
*Pass requesting code*
</b:if>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "link of the category"'>
*Pass requesting code*
</b:if>
```

And

Specific Label Page

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == "foo"'>
*Pass requesting code*
</b:if>
```

No one works.

Thank you so much.
In other words, execute code if the post is a specified category.

Comment: Bad and dangerous idea(if security is important to you)! You should never handle passwords on client side. Use a server side language like php in combo with a database.

Comment: Thats an example. The password is ok.